# JW Player load HD plugin locally

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I've been trying to get the HD plugin to load locally using the jw embedder code. I know you need to use the full URL for local plugins but I can't get the parameters to work. Also do you need the hd.js file loaded as well? 
Does some one have an example they can share of this in action?
This does not work.

```
plugins: {hd:"http://www.mysite.com/swf/files/hd.swf" { file:"http://www.mysites.com/vid/file.mp4", fullscreen: false,state: true },                            
        },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it the wrong way, here is how to do it.
You don't need to specify `"hd: <the url>"`, just the url is enough if you want to serve the file locally.

```
plugins: {
    "http://www.example.com/swf/files/hd.swf": {
        file: "http://www.example.com/vid/file.mp4", 
        fullscreen: false,
        state: true 
    }                            
}
```

Comment: I finally figured it out, but since you answered it I will give it to you. Thanks